# Migration from apache ignite 2.7.0 to 2.10.0

Tags: ignite

Planning to migrate from apache ignite 2.7.0 to apache ignite 2.10.0.

***Is there any guide/blog/way to migrate without losing any data?***

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it a persistent cluster? If you don't have in-mem regions, then I suppose you should be able to just deactivate the old cluster, update the jars and start a new version

Comment: In the case of an in-memory try to load your data to an external source. The easiest way is to load data into CSV files and after upgrade load data from CSV into the cluster.